# Having Issue on Setting Slideing div Button and Size

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/yHPTv/3272/) and let me know how I can separate the `.clickme` box from the `.slidecontent`? I need to change the Height of the .slidecontent`for example to`height:300px;` but this also change the grey shadow to 300px

What I need to have is having the `.slidecontent` with height of 300 and looks like the third (green arrow)

[image]

```js
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
});
```

```css
#slideout {
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 45%;
    left:-280px;
}
    
#clickme {
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #ff0000;
}

#slidecontent {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        Yar, there be dragonns herre!
    </div>
    <div id="clickme">
         >
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do but your jQuery code refers to the parent of `clickme` which is `slideout`, not `slidecontent` and it is probable that this is causing the undesired effect. Is there a reason you are not referencing `slidecontent` directly?

Comment: thanks SunKnight0, no not really , what I want is only creating a tab which let the content be slide

Comment: Try moving the background: #666; from `slideout` to `slidecontent`